# how join tables in optimized way

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web-development-server

hellow.I have  3 table like below;

**Movie** Table like this:

```
+------+-------+-----+
| id   | name  |     |
+------+-------+-----+
+------+-------+-----+
| 1    | got   |     |
+------+-------+-----+
+------+-------+-----+
| 2    | Drive |     |
+------+-------+-----+
+------+-------+-----+
| 3    | Thor  |     |
+------+-------+-----+
```

**Janra**:

```
+------+-------------+
| id   | janra_name  |
+------+-------------+
+------+-------------+
| 1    | action      |
+------+-------------+
+------+-------------+
| id   | comedy      |
+------+-------------+
```

Movie_janra: (movie_id is a foreign key to id in movie table)

```
+--------+-------------+
| mov_id |  janra_id   |
+--------+-------------+
+--------+-------------+
| 1      | 1           |
+--------+-------------+
+--------+-------------+
| 1      | 2           |
+--------+-------------+
```

**nation** Table:

```
 +------+-------------+
    | id   | name        |
    +------+-------------+
    +------+-------------+
    | 1   | us           |
    +------+-------------+
    +------+-------------+
    | 2   | uk           |
    +------+-------------+
```

movie_nation Table:

```
    +------+-------------+
    |mov_id| nation_id   |
    +------+-------------+
    +------+-------------+
    | 1    |      1      |
    +------+-------------+
    +------+-------------+
    | 1    |      2      |
    +------+-------------+
```

then i use query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT movie.id,
          movie.name,
          f.janra_name
   FROM `movie`
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT mj.movie_id,
             janra.janra_name
      FROM movie_janra AS mj
      LEFT JOIN janra ON mj.janra_id=janra.id) AS f ON f.movie_id=movie.id) AS ll
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT movie_nation.movie_id,
          nation.nation
   FROM movie_nation
   INNER JOIN nation ON nation.id=movie_nation.nation_id) AS rr ON rr.movie_id=ll.id
```

(join `movie` with result of (`movie_janra` and `janra`)) AS ll  this give me all movies with all janra like below

```
id name janra 
1   got  action
1   got  comedy
```

then i join this with result of  (join `movie_nation` with `nation`) AS `rr` ON `rr.movie_id = ll.id`

but this query result is like this

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|    id     |     name    |     janra   |  nation  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|    1      |     got     |     action  |  us      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|    1      |     got     |     action  |  uk      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|    id     |     name    |     comedy  |  us      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|    id     |     name    |     comedy  |  uk      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

I use MySQL.

This result is more than I want. I want two row. Thank you all.

Comment: Its unclear why sub-queries are used. You can use multiple JOINS. e.g. `SELECT  FROM x JOIN y ON x.a=y.b JOIN z ON z.a=.x.a ....`

Comment: can you give me a query?

Comment: In table "Janra", you have a value "Id" in column "Id". Is that expected or that should be 2 actually? And please add your expected output with the question as well with clear logic.

Comment: I want something like this: row1(got action US) row2( got comedy UK) and the rows as much as biggest count between column janra and nation.and the id in column id is mistake it should be 2

Comment: What should the output look like?  See `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  I suggest that the tables are "over-normalized".

Answer (score 1):

First thing, remove the tables movie_nation and movie_janra then just move the columns to movie table as shown below then retain all the other tables:
[Database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2k7i.png)

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2k7i.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf6MU.png

then I have added table data: 
[movie table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDYc3.png) 
[Janra table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quC7t.png) 
[Nation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JItTe.png)

Then use this code to get your desired output:

```
select a.id,a.movie_name,b.janra_name, c.nation_name
from movie a 
left outer join janra b
on a.janra_id = b.id
left outer join nation c
on a.nation_id = c.id;
```

Just select the ID and Movie name to movie table then left outer join to nation and janra table using their corresponding IDs from table movie to get the janra_name and nation_name.

This is the ouput of it: [query output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2k7i.png)

Comment: good attempt at first answer. Include the data in the answer itself rather than as links.

Comment: i want to movie have multiple nation and janra .if I remove movie_nation and movie_janra table then that isn't possible to have one movie with multiple janra and nation

Comment: whats the difference of it? while Daniyal Madmolil already have the data?

Comment: It is possible. just post your desired ouput then ill code it for you sir. regards.

Comment: the difference is that I want to show all movie item on a page that each has sub detail like nations  and janras then I want show multiple janra and the nation of each movie in its item

Comment: No the first comment is for danblack sorry. hehehe wait i already have the solution you want

Comment: I want something like this: row1(got action US)  row2( got comedy UK) and the rows as much as biggest count between column janra and nation

Answer (score 0):

based on the previous answer, you just need to change the data type of janra_id and nation_id from movie table from int to varchar. then you can now use multiple janras and nation using comma separated values.

use this new code to achieve that.

```
select a.id, a.movie_name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct a.janra_name) janra_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct a.nation_name) nation_name
from (
select a.*,b.janra_name,c.nation_name
from movie a
left outer join janra b
on FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.janra_id)
left outer join nation c
on FIND_IN_SET(c.id, a.nation_id)
order by a.movie_name ) a
group by a.movie_name;
```

Here is the sample data:[image]

And here is the output of the query: [image]

Comment: yes, its works but for searching all the movies(like 1 million) with janra action and nation UK this query I think to be slow.right?

Comment: i haven't tried yet. I would suggest to use "Limit" and "offset" for searching millions of datasets. It is used for paginating query results.